# "Entre mortos e feridos, salvaram-se todos." Como entender este ditado?

Tags: significado, ditados

Estou com dificuldade em entender o ditado

> Entre mortos e feridos, salvaram-se todos.

Quando uma pessoa diz isto, significa que…

- apesar do perigo ou dificuldade, nada de mal aconteceu? ou…
- o mal que aconteceu não foi muito mau—não nos matou/quebrou? ou…
- o mal que aconteceu não atingiu os que são importante para nós?

No seu sentido literal, será que a frase significa que…

- No meio de outras pessoas que ficaram mortas ou feridas, todas **"as nossas" ficaram ilesas**? ou…
- O falante só **começou a dizer** que no meio de pessoas mortas e feridas, algumas pessoas ficaram ilesas. Mas felizmente, **ninguém ficou nem morto nem ferido**? ou…
- **Entre as possibilidades** das pessoas ficarem mortas, feridas, ou salvas, ficaram salvas? ou…
- …outra explicação?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Literalmente, «entre mortos e feridos, salvaram-se todos» não tem sentido. Trata-se na verdade de uma modificação brincalhona do ditado:

> Entre mortos e feridos, alguém há de escapar.

Este compreende-se facilmente. Pelo que eu vi pela net, a variante brincalhona é usada, como seria de esperar, sempre jocosamente, e é aplicada a situações potencialmente perigosas ou em que alguém previa perigo, mas em que no fim tudo corre mais ou menos bem.

Por exemplo, [neste artigo (2012)](http://www.fabiocampana.com.br/2012/08/entre-mortos-e-feridos-salvaram-se-todos/) o 'ditado' refere-se a um debate entre candidatos a prefeito de Curitiba, em que todos os participantes se declararam vencedores. Neste [outro artigo (2014)](http://www.correiodopovo.com.br/blogs/hiltormombach/?p=32761) refere-se ao facto de, depois de previsões catastróficas, os jogos do Mundial de 2014 em Porto Alegre terem decorrido sem incidentes. Este outro caso [(Rabecão capota: entre mortos e feridos salvaram-se todos!)](https://jornaloexpresso.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/rabecao-capota-entre-mortos-e-feridos-salvaram-se-todos/) até envolveu mortos: o rabecão transportava cadáveres, mas a tripulação sofreu apenas alguns ferimentos.

Diz a [Wikipédia que foi Washington Rodrigues (1936-)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington_Rodrigues), jornalista desportivo, treinador de futebol e dirigente desportivo brasileiro, quem cunhou esta variante brincalhona. Mas não, ela já existia em 1906, vinte anos antes de Washington Rodrigues nascer (negrito meu):

> A policia prohibiu a representação de tal drama historico, que transformou o Theatro Nacional em campo de batalha de dois partidos politicos encarniçadamente inimigos.
>   **Entre mortos e feridos todos escaparam**, como sempre se dá […]
>   [Francisco Mascarenhas, *Do Brazil ao Chile através dos Andes*, 1906.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=A9YpAQAAMAAJ&q=%22escaparam,%20como%20sempre%20se%20d%C3%A1%22&dq=%22escaparam,%20como%20sempre%20se%20d%C3%A1%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEsOHpvbnWAhUFSRoKHc0OD8kQ6AEIJjAA)

A versão original—*entre mortos e feridos alguém há de escapar*—já existia em 1878 [(Manuel Pereira Lobato, *Agua de Lourdes: comedia em um acto*)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt/search?q1=%22mortos%20e%20feridos%20alguem%20ha%20de%20escapar%22&id=hvd.hnz89k&view=1up&seq=1).

Comment: Talvez um trocadilho brincalhão que também se faz com o ditado "uma faca de dois legumes", na palavra legumes se pronuncia bem fortemente e claramente pra chamar a atenção re que está errada e se tornar engraçado. Sendo o correto "uma faca de dois gumes".

Comment: @Dan, afinal este novo ditado é muito mais antigo do que dizia a Wikipédia. Alguém tem paciência para lá ir emendar?

Comment: @Jacinto - Empresta-me a metralhadora, e talvez eu vá ao antro de cobras tentar salvar esse pequeno pedacinho da verdade... até que o dono da versão equivocada reapareça e restaure a peta.

Comment: Usamos muito essa expressão no Brasil.  Contexto: a expectativa de um acontecimento ruim mas que não se confirma como tal, ou então, passar por acontecimentos potencialmente prejudiciais mas que no final das contas não nos fizeram mal.  Todos saíram ilesos.  "Entre mortos e feridos, salvaram-se todos".  Literalmente não faz sentido, mas o significado e o uso não são literais.

Comment: Pra mim a frase faz sentido. Imagina um campo onde está acontecendo uma guerra e o exército precisou recuar. Esse exército que recuou conseguiu recolher todos os feridos em campo e também todos os mortos em batalha.

Comment: @Vinicius, isso é um uso muito curioso da palavra *salvar*. Se um comandante militar me dissesse que tinha salvado todos os mortos e feridos, eu iria querer saber que é que ele queria dizer com "salvar os mortos".

Answer (score 1):

Apesar dos percalços, tudo deu certo no final!

Answer (score -1):

Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas uma resposta satisfatória sempre será bem vinda. Digo isso porque eu pesquiso muito na internet e gosto de ver vários pontos de vista.
Pressuposto: situação de grave crise. Apesar de a fala nos levar a pensar em uma situação militar; pode ser militar, política, social, não importa. A chave é: parecer ser um “mato sem cachorro” (outro ditado). Uma situação difícil, com péssimo prognóstico. Mas, ao final, no cômputo de perdas e ganhos, vê-se que a situação não se desenrolou de modo tão ruim (como era esperado). Houve “baixas” (perdas), mas a situação final pode ser tida como perfeitamente aceitável.

Answer (score -2):

Entendo que se você for ver pelo lado espiritual refere-se à salvação da alma.

Mas se você for pelo outro lado eu entendo o seguinte:

Por mais difícil que seja a situação, que muitas das vezes não encontramos uma saída, sempre haverá uma luz no fim do túnel, ou seja, sempre aparecerá um caminho a seguir no meio de muitas tempestades.

Answer (score -2):

Os que morreram  todos foram pra Deus.
Os que ficaram feridos foram socorridos.
Os que saíram ilesos voltaram para os seus... Todos foram salvos.

Ou também o resgate dos corpos, por exemplo em acidentes marítimos/naufragados onde não se encontram os corpos e dão estes por mortos. Neste caso pode se dizer que não se salvaram todos, pois somente os feridos e os não feridos foram encontrados 100%.